# Trouble building executable jar in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, manifest, executable-jar

I'm trying to export my project to a jar file in IntelliJ using [these instructions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/), and failing.

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on this line in my application:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

Note that this same project exports fine in Eclipse.

I've tried changing the `Class-Path` in the manifest to `.`, as I've noticed this change in the jar exported by Eclipse.

Then, my application gets a bit further, but bails when trying to load any of the resource files included in my jar. This is how:

Assume my jar is placed in

```
/Users/me/screwed.jar
```

When my application tries to open `resource.file` in the root of the jar file, it's searching for it here:

```
/Users/me/resource.file
```

This triggers a `NullPointerException`.

How do I fix this, team?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to load your path:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

This should be the root of your jar file and allow you to open resources within it.

For static context, use

```
MyStaticClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

where MyStaticClassName is some staic utility class.

Comment: What about for arbitrary file types? Also, its unfortunate to have to modify my code for a build issue, I'd rather like to fix the build process.

Comment: I'm frequently passing around `File` objects in my application, each of which I instantiate by extending the path obtained in my question.

Comment: Thanks, thing is, I need it in static contexts too, where what you've suggested won't work (I think)

Comment: Another edit made. I would make MyStaticClassName a utility class that exposes a method to return the path which all your other classes can share.

Comment: This still works in the IDE, but nulls out in the exported jar :(